# Game fighting function broken

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I've tried to make a  fighting function for my game in python, whenever it calls, the game just keeps subtracting health from both p1 and p2, getting both of them well into the negatives.

Code:

```
def fight(p1, p1atk, p2, p2atk):
    while p1 > 0 or p2 > 0:
        # who hits
        order = random.randint(1, 2)
        if order == 1:
            print('')
            print('you manage to strike')
            p1atkc = p1atk
            p2 -= p1atkc
            print('you hit him for ' + str(p1atkc) + " damage!")
            print('your hp:' + str(p1) + '| Ogre health: ' + str(p2))
        if order == 2:
            print('')
            print('the Ogre struck you!')
            p2atkc = p2atk
            p1 -= p2atkc
            print('you were hit for ' + str(p2atkc) + ' damage!')
            print('your hp:' + str(p1) + '| Ogre health: ' + str(p2))
    else:
        if p2 >= 1:
            w = "Ogre"
        elif p1 >= 1:
            w = "you"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your while condition seems wrong. For the fight to go an both have to have more then 0 life left.
So it must mean:

```
while p1 > 0 and p2 > 0:
    ...
```